# Spacemacs layer documentation

Tags: spacemacs, documentation

In `~/.emacs.d/layers/.../any-given-layer` there is almost always a `README` documenting this layer's functionality. Is there a key binding, or function that opens the `README` associated with a given layer?

I find this necessary because layers bundle functionality from various packages, e.g. a repl package, package for the major mode of the language, snippets, etc., and I often need to reference the `README` to see what's in the layer and how to use it.

Thanks,
chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of May 2016, for `develop` branch of Spacemacs, the command is `helm-spacemacs-help-layers` under <kbd>Space h l</kbd> (assuming <kbd>Space</kbd> is your [leader key](http://spacemacs.org/doc/DOCUMENTATION#orgheadline54)). It will open a [Helm](http://spacemacs.org/doc/DOCUMENTATION#orgheadline87) buffer with all layers available in your Spacemacs. Choose a layer, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and you will end up in the layer's README file.

Also, while still browsing the list of layers in Helm, press <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> (this switches from list of completions to list of actions) and you can choose another action to do with that layer. E.g. you can open this layer's `package.el` file.

For stable version 0.105 of Spacemacs you can just call <kbd>Space h Space</kbd> (`helm-spacemacs`), and you'll see the list of layers along other documentation-related entries. You can use <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> here as well, and you can use <kbd>Space h Space</kbd> in `develop` branch as well.